# Rounding up integer without using float, double, or division

Tags: c, math, rounding

Its an embedded platform thats why such restrictions.

```
original equation: 0.02035*c*c - 2.4038*c
```

Did this:

```
int32_t val = 112; // this value is arbitrary
int32_t result = (val*((val * 0x535A8) - 0x2675F70));
result = result>>24;
```

The precision is still poor. When we multiply `val*0x535A8` Is there a way we can further improve the precision by rounding up, but without using any float, double, or division.

Comment: How long are your longest integers? Do you have a maximum value for the input `c`? I want to judge how many bits you can work with.

Comment: The maximum value I would be using is 120 (for C). The integers can be 32 bit long.

Comment: What precision do you want? The calculation you are doing basically casts a fairly precise fixed-point value to an integer, and the largest possible value of the integer is just 4.

Comment: What is the minimum value for c?

Comment: Minimum value would be 1

Comment: For only 120 input values, you could easily use a lookup table.

Comment: Have to save codespace..

Comment: For the result calculated in floating point, how is it converted to an integer? Truncation or rounding?

Comment: I am not using any floating point right now. But if you meant that if we do floating point math here without using float variable intializations, then to convert it into integert, Rounding should be ideal.

Comment: I was just curious to know why you thought the result was inaccurate - I assumed you were comparing the output of the two calculation methods. See the update of my answer for the simple way to round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not precision. You're using plenty of bits.

I suspect the problem is that you're comparing two different methods of converting to `int`. The first is a cast of a `double`, the second is a truncation by right-shifting.

Converting floating point to integer simply drops the fractional part, leading to a *round towards zero*; right-shifting does a *round down* or floor. For positive numbers there's no difference, but for negative numbers the two methods will be 1 off from each other. See an example at http://ideone.com/rkckuy and some background reading at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer).

Your original code is easy to fix:

```
int32_t result = (val*((val * 0x535A8) - 0x2675F70));
if (result < 0)
    result += 0xffffff;
result = result>>24;
```

See the results at http://ideone.com/D0pNPF

You might also just decide that the right shift result is OK as is. The conversion error isn't greater than it is for the other method, just different.

**Edit:** If you want to do rounding instead of truncation the answer is even easier.

```
int32_t result = (val*((val * 0x535A8) - 0x2675F70));
result = (result + (1L << 23)) >> 24;
```

I'm going to join in with some of the others in suggesting that you use a constant expression to replace those magic constants with something that documents how they were derived.

```
static const int32_t a = (int32_t)(0.02035 * (1L << 24) + 0.5);
static const int32_t b = (int32_t)(2.4038 * (1L << 24) + 0.5);
int32_t result = (val*((val * a) - b));
```

Comment: BTW: In an embedded environment, 16-bit `int` is prevalent.  Suggest `((int32_t) 1 << 24)` to prevent UB and provide maximum portability.  (or at least `(1L << 24)`).

Answer (score 2):

How about just scaling your constants by 10000. The maximum number you then get is 2035*120*120 - 24038*120 = 26419440, which is far below the 2^31 limit. So maybe there is no need to do real bit-tweaking here.

As noted by Joe Hass, your problem is that you shift your precision bits into the dustbin.

Whether shifting your decimals by 2 or by 10 to the left does actually not matter. Just pretend your decimal point is not behind the last bit but at the shifted position. If you keep computing with the result, shifting by 2 is likely easier to handle. If you just want to output the result, shift by powers of ten as proposed above, convert the digits and insert the decimal point 5 characters from the right.

Answer (score 1):

Givens:

Lets assume 1 <= c <= 120,
**original equation: 0.02035*c*c - 2.4038*c**
then -70.98586 < f(c) < 4.585
--> `-71 <= result <= 5`
rounding f(c) to nearest `int32_t`.
Arguments A = 0.02035 and B = 2.4038
A & B may change a bit with subsequent compiles, but not at run-time.

---

Allow coder to input values like 0.02035 & 2.4038.  The key components shown here and by others it to scale the factors like 0.02035 to by some power-of-2, do the equation (simplified into the form (A*c - B)*c) and the scale the result back.

Important features:

1 When determining A and B, insure the compile time floating point multiplication and final conversion occurs via a round and not a truncation.  With positive values, the `+ 0.5` achieves that. Without a rounded answer `UD_A*UD_Scaling` could end up just under a whole number and truncate away 0.999999 when converting to the `int32_t`

2 Instead of doing expensive division at run-time, we do >> (right shift).  By adding half the divisor (as suggested by @Joe Hass), before the division, we get a nicely rounded answer.  It is important *not* to code in `/` here as `some_signed_int / 4` and `some_signed_int >> 2` do not round the same way.  With 2's complement, `>>` truncates toward `INT_MIN` whereas `/` truncates toward 0.

```
#define UD_A          (0.02035)
#define UD_B          (2.4038)
#define UD_Shift      (24)
#define UD_Scaling    ((int32_t) 1 << UD_Shift)
#define UD_ScA        ((int32_t) (UD_A*UD_Scaling + 0.5))
#define UD_ScB        ((int32_t) (UD_B*UD_Scaling + 0.5))

for (int32_t val = 1; val <= 120; val++) {
  int32_t result = ((UD_A*val - UD_B)*val + UD_Scaling/2) >> UD_Shift; 
  printf("%" PRId32 "%" PRId32 "\n", val, result);
}
```

---

Example differences:

```
val,   OP equation,  OP code, This code
  1,      -2.38345,       -3,       -2
 54,     -70.46460,      -71,      -70
120,       4.58400,        4,        5
```

This is a new answer.  My old +1 answer deleted.

Comment: Except for the addition of `UD_Scaling/2` here I don't see how this differs from the code in the question. If you look at the hex constants you'll see that they're exactly the ones you're calculating.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Good point.  Hmmm. The OP method used to calculate the constants is not shown.  Here it is explicit - good for future ref.  The values like `0.02035`, I assume, may change between complies but are in the ballpark.  Without knowing OP's method, OP's scaled constants and the ones here may differ should A or B change. OP's cursorily states "The precision is poor".  If OP is always doing the same scaling as I, aside from the `UD_Scaling/2`, there is not more precision available. The answers only vary from -71 to 5 in integer steps and the `UD_Scaling/2` gets the best `int32_t` answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you r input uses max 7 bits and you have 32 bit available then your best bet is to shift everything by as many bits as possible and work with that:

```
int32_t result;
result = (val * (int32_t)(0.02035 * 0x1000000)) - (int32_t)(2.4038 * 0x1000000);
result >>= 8; // make room for another 7 bit multiplication
result *= val;
result >>= 16;
```

Constant conversion will be done by an optimising compiler at compile time.

Comment: I didnt quite understand this answer @Sergey. By shifting everything, arent we going to lose the precision. Honestly, I didnt understand the answer. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @UnderDog Precision = number of bits you work with. `float` has a precision of 23 bits, `double` of 52 bits. By shifting the integers to the maximum values we use the full precision of 32 bit integers. Since the result is an integer we need to shift the result back to the right amount.